# What would be the product of following elimination reaction?

Tags: carbonyl-compounds, organometallic-compounds, elimination

**Question**
[image]

**Doubt**

The answer is given B. But why cant it be C after all formation of cyclopropane would increase angle strain?

Comment: Where are the most acidic hydrogens?

Comment: At adjacent site of C=O. But how come compound B is stable . I mean in E2 first Cl- should leave and after that OH- abstracts proton, but it seems here than it is following E1cb?

Comment: [3] rings are reasonably stable, lots of examples of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you notice is an alcoholic base reacting with a molecule. The base looks for the most acidic hydrogen in the molecule. Since the no.of moles of $alc.KOH$ is not mentioned, we go for both the acidic hydrogens at the adjacent positions to the carbonyl functional group. Once the acidic hydrogens are abstracted, it's a simple elimination of $Cl$ that will happen.

[image]

I agree with the comment made by @Waylander as there are plenty of examples with three-membered rings. Well, (c) is not possible but you can say (a) is a possibility. Of course (a) forms too by a simple elimination reaction but the most probable one is the abstraction of acidic hydrogen in the molecule. The stability of [3]rings can be brought about by [banana bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bent_bond).